# QAbstractListModel does not get updated with values when data is loaded from CSV, but it does when using hardcoded values

Tags: python, csv, pyqt4, pyqtgraph, emit

I've made a scaled down app in a single script to specifically tackle this problem. Code paste is [here](http://pastebin.com/DcwPsvNd).

When I press "auto ROI" the app simply takes the hard-coded coordinates and plots them to the `pyqtgraph` view:

[image]

When I try to "load anatomical coordinates" from a textfile (see below) everything seems to work as intended except the names of the ROIs are not showing up in the ROI list in the bottom right. This widget is an `RoiItemModel` (which is a `QAbstractListModel`)

[image]

Here is the text file I used:

```
1) ROI Name, 2) Length, 3) X Coordinate, 4) Y Coordinate
AC, 3, 0.5, 0.0
V1, 3, 2.5, -2.5
M2, 3, 1.5, 1.75
BC, 3, 3.5, -1.0
RS, 3, 0.5, -2.5
M1, 3, 1.0, 2.5
HL, 3, 2.0, 0.0
HL2, 4, -2.0, 0.0
HL3, 6, -3.5, 1.0
```

While debugging I find that calling the following line of code with identical parameters appears to give two different results:

```
self.dataChanged.emit(self.index(row), self.index(row)) # in RoiItemModel
```

The only thing that is different (as far as I can tell) is in one case I have my data hard-coded (works) and in the other case I use csv.reader to first convert the values to an identical format (doesn't work)

### Bonus Information:

I save the path of all the rois to a JSON file I use `QSettings` to load this at runtime so that the list is immediately populated with ROI names. In my main program (not the pastebein example), if I exit my program and rerun it then the roi names are loaded from file and correctly populated in `RoiItemModel` such that the names display.

I've tried making it so that the location of the ROI's loaded from the csv are stored in `self.data` - *exactly where the hard-coded coordinates are stored* - and then only after a button is pressed are the coordinates from `self.data` used to plot the ROI's *and it still fails*

So basically this:

- hardcoded `self.data` -> press button to call function that uses `self.data` -> works
- load from csv and store in `self.data` -> press button to call function that uses `self.data` -> doesn't work.

Strange.

Comment: If i were to guess i would suspect a typing issue. PyQt often has significant issues with python types. An examination of the values called into this line of code might prove helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic code is here:

```
def load_ROI_table(self):
    ...
    roi_names = [roi_table[x, 0] for x in roi_table_range]
    print(roi_names)
```

which gives this very misleading output:

```
['AC', 'V1', 'M2', 'BC', 'RS', 'M1', 'HL', 'HL2', 'HL3']
```

This is a really poor design choice in numpy, because the objects in that list are not python strings:

```
print(['%s %r' % (type(i), i) for i in roi_names])
...
["<class 'numpy.str_'> 'AC'", "<class 'numpy.str_'> 'V1'", "<class 'numpy.str_'> 'M2'", "<class 'numpy.str_'> 'BC'", "<class 'numpy.str_'> 'RS'", "<class 'numpy.str_'> 'M1'", "<class 'numpy.str_'> 'HL'", "<class 'numpy.str_'> 'HL2'", "<class 'numpy.str_'> 'HL3'"]
```

Qt knows nothing about such numpy types, so you have to take care to convert them to ordinary python types:

```
roi_names = [str(roi_table[x, 0]) for x in roi_table_range]
```